# How to crawl a website with pagination using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, pagination, web-crawler

I am writing a web scraper with google script and want to make my script run until the last page of a specific website automatically.

My script works well on: https://www.louvre.fr/conferences-et-colloques , but I'd like to make it works on every single pages without specify the number of pages manually. Is there a way to make my script click on the "next page" button and loop it?

Best,

Comment: For example, how about using the query parameter of `page`?

Comment: Try searching for all anchor tags in the recovered page.